# youtube-dl mp4 or mkv and 720p or less

Tags: youtube-dl, omxplayer

I'm using a video player that can't play webm video files. (omxplayer on raspberry pi). And i'm trying to have all of my downloaded videos not be webm. mp4 or mkv work.

This is what I have in my config, but it still downloads it as webm. What settings can I use to guarantee it can play on omxplayer on a raspberry pi?

```
-f 'bestvideo[height<=720]+bestvideo[ext!=webm]+bestaudio[ext!=webm]'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using and it worked.

```
bestvideo[ext!=webm][height<=1080]+bestaudio[ext!=webm]/best[ext!=webm]
```